# Google Chrome cannot detect PWA on Desktop System?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've completed the basic criteria for PWA as [google documents](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) said and using *secure connection over https, having registered service worker*. I've installed successfully PWA on android and IOS devices. Now I want to install my reactJS web site as PWA Desktop but I cannot make it successful. is I missed something?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"short_name": "PWA DESKTOP",
"name": "PWA DESKTOP",
"theme_color": "#2196f3",
"background_color": "#2196f3",
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "/",
"icons": [
 {
  "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
  "sizes": "72x72",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
  "sizes": "96x96",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
  "sizes": "128x128",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
  "sizes": "144x144",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
  "sizes": "152x152",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
  "sizes": "384x384",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
  "sizes": "512x512",
  "type": "image/png"
 }]
}
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? According to official Chrome documentation,  you need at least v73 to support PWA on desktop; https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/desktop

Comment: I'm using google chrome **Version 79.0.3945.88** . Still chrome not detecting it.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: Have you checked ( chrome://apps/ ) in Chrome and removed any previous installs/tests of your app?

Comment: which windows version you are using to test PWA desktop

Comment: @Mathias I've checked in [Chrome Apps](chrome://apps). My web app is not installed already. 

What does mean when running as HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA ?

Comment: @RajeshG I'm testing my PWA web Application on **windows 10 version 1803 (OS Build 17134.885)**

Comment: There is a tool built into Chrome to check your PWA and help with any issues you may have. More here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse

Comment: @Mathias sure I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the issue why my PWA DESKTOP was not working. I've created custom service worker to integrate push notifications and while registration of service worker, I overrides the create-react-app service worker which uses workbox for managing service worker.

After combining custom and CRA generated service worker will do the work.